# Minimal implementation of JavaFX TextInputArea

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2, rich-text-editor

I'm investigating the best way to write a rich text editor in JavaFX - don't mention the HTMLEditor to me: we've spent literally months hacking at it and I could write reams about why it isn't suitable for our purposes!  Choice at the moment is to extend AnchorPane and do all of the layout, navigation etc. from scratch or to extend TextInputArea, which looks as though it would help.  Anyone have their own implementation of that or would like to propose a minimal implementation?

FWIW here's a scrap from me:

public class TryPain3 extends TextInputControl {
    private AnchorPane rootNode = new AnchorPane();

```
public TryPain3() {
    super(new Content() {
        private String text = "";

        @Override
        public String get(int i, int i1) {
            return text.substring(i, i1);
        }

        @Override
        public void insert(int i, String string, boolean bln) {
        }

        @Override
        public void delete(int i, int i1, boolean bln) {
        }

        @Override
        public int length() {
            return text.length();
        }

        @Override
        public String get() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public void addListener(ChangeListener<? super String> cl) {

        }

        @Override
        public void removeListener(ChangeListener<? super String> cl) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public String getValue() {
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public void addListener(InvalidationListener il) {

        }

        @Override
        public void removeListener(InvalidationListener il) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    });

    setEditable(true);

    Text text1 = new Text("fred was here");
    text1.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 18));
    text1.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);

    text1.setFontSmoothingType(FontSmoothingType.LCD);

    rootNode.getChildren().add(text1);


    setSkin(new TP3Skin(this, rootNode));

}


class TP3Skin implements Skin<TryPain3> {
    TryPain3 tp;
    Node root;

    public TP3Skin(TryPain3 tp, Node root) {
        this.tp = tp;
        this.root = root;
    }


    @Override
    public TryPain3 getSkinnable() {
        return tp;
    }

    @Override
    public Node getNode() {
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        tp = null;
        rootNode = null;
    }

}
```

}

It looks as though the skin is not optional.

Questions I'd like to find out are things like:

- how is the UI supposed to be drawn - I'm quite happy to code it from scratch but how to get benefit of calls to forward() as an example
- should the UI creation be done in the Skin?
- whether the base class deals with things like where to put the cursor if you click on a bit of text

I'm sure other questions will arise from this.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: No.  I was basically forced to go back to HTMLEditor which really is awful but less awful than going this route ;-) ( possibly.  Or several of the other routes I tried )  On the plus side, it looks as though there has been some progress on that control so when I can face going back to it I might pull out less of my remaining hair.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try next JavaFX 8.0 control `TextFlow`, which allows aggregation of various text styles. See examples here: https://wikis.oracle.com/display/OpenJDK/Rich+Text+API+Samples

JavaFX 8 is part of JDK8. So you can download developers build here http://jdk8.java.net/download.html and it will include JavaFX and new TextFlow control.

Comment: Yes - that would be ideal, is it something I can get hold of now?  If so I'd appreciate a pointer!

Comment: Early TextFlow implementations will start appearing in [JDK8 preview builds](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html). You want an editor though Mike and TextFlow is a display only API even in jdk8.  You could use TextFlow as a basis to build a rich text editor and something simple would probably not be too hard but IMO for something complex like a full featured Word Processor, it would be awfully difficult to do well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment jewelsea - looks like my original question is still open.  "full featured Word Processor" is rather more than I'm trying for but while HTMLEditor looks as though it would do the trick, after pages of JavaScript ( which is not simple to debug even in a normal environment ) the real problem is the HTML that comes out of it ( including a <font> tag which was deprecated for HTML 4! ).  Basically it is just too flaky to use if you need to do something with the HTML other than place it in another web browser!

Comment: Thanks for adding the link Sergey.  Based on the comment from jewelsea I'm going to have to deal with all of the input aspects - mouse clicks, navigation etc. plus using a preview release so I think we're going to go with a fairly clean-sheet approach.  Looking at the source for TextArea there are 3 main classes in the MVC framework - the control itself, the Content being the model and the Skin as the view/GUI.  They add a 'behaviour' class to deal with navigation 'gestures'.  Main issue is to deal with the font metrics but I saw somewhere else there is an API available for that...